# Error while query a Textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

This should be a simple solution but Visual Studio 2012 give me errors that say sqlCon is a field but is used like a type and the same error for Textbox1...  Maybe I am missing an assembly reference or proper connection imports?  I'm looking to continue this simple route.

```
    MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection("Server=***;Port=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;");
    MySqlCommand commandText = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT count(Dues) From Students");
        sqlCon.CommandText = "SELECT * count(Dues) FROM Students";
        sqlCon.Connection = sqlCon;
        TextBox1.Text = sqlCon.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: I think you have missed connection.open()

Comment: It seems you forget opening the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open the connection
- use `using` statements
- use `Try-catch` block

Snippet,

```
string connStr = "Server=***;Port=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;";
string query = "SELECT count(Dues) From Students";
using(MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(MySqlCommand sqlComm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlComm.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            TextBox1.Text = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There weren't any errors in this, however, Textbox1 says it does not exist in the current context.  The above code so far only seems to work within the Form_Load function.  Any suggestions on placement etc.?

Comment: the code can work on its own. so better wrap it in a method and call that method everytime you need to query in the db. what is the exact error thrwn?

Comment: It looks like most issues are sorted out, the error now spits out a SQL syntax error on: SELECT SUM(Dues Paid) From Students  ;  I am relatively new with SQL but this seems correct as-is.

Comment: is this the query you are using `SELECT SUM(Dues Paid) From Students`? since the column `Dues Paid` contains space, you should wrap it with backtick eg, SELECT SUM(\`Dues Paid\`) From Students

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection("Server=***;Port=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;");
MySqlCommand commandText = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT count(Dues) From Students");

//sqlCon is of type MySqlConnection which is derived from DbConnection
sqlCon.CommandText = "SELECT * count(Dues) FROM Students";

//sqlCon has no Connection property, and why are you even assigning sqlCon to that property
sqlCon.Connection = sqlCon;

//ofcourse this will fail
TextBox1.Text = sqlCon.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

I believe what you're trying to achieve is:

```
MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection("Server=***;Port=***;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***;");
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT count(Dues) From Students");

try
{
  sqlCon.Open();
  command.Connection = sqlCon;
  TextBox1.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
finally
{
  sqlCon.Close();
}
```